# What is under the Underdark?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, lore

Amongst D&D players, especially those familiar with the Forgotten Realms setting, the existence of the Underdark is well-known. This world beneath the surface has even made it into many other campaigns, and into Pathfinder-related content.

I feel I must ask, since I cannot find an answer anywhere:

**What is beneath the Underdark?**

I'm limiting the scope of my question to the Forgotten Realms setting, since it's the canon setting as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80261/discussion-on-question-by-user102021-what-is-under-the-underdark).

Comment: RE: "I'm limiting the scope of my question to the Forgotten Realms setting, since it's the canon setting as far as I'm aware." While the Realms is the default *5e* setting, for *3e* it was Greyhawk, and for earlier there was no default setting. Should this also be a *5e* question?

Answer (score 11):

### [The Lowerdark](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Lowerdark)

The Underdark is actually made up of several layers. The Upperdark, what normal people from the world above would call the caves and caverns underneath the ground, is the kind of place Dwarves and Drow would encounter one-another.

The Middledark is the Underdark proper as we know it. It's where all the 'Underdark' adventures take place, with Drow, Duergar and Mind Flayers.

The Lowerdark is even further down, and is a place where even the Drow fear treading. What limited information we have seems to suggest that the primary inhabitants are more Mind Flayers.

As for what lies beneath the Lowerdark? Nobody alive in Toril seems to know for certain. Some seem to think there's portals to the Plane of Fire, others think it's just more Mind Flayers and you'd be insane to try and find out.

Most information we have comes from the [D&D 3.5 *Underdark* sourcebook](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Underdark_(sourcebook)).

Comment: While this answer may be true, it could be improved by providing citations for the claims.

Comment: For reference, the Forgotten Realms wiki article you link to almost exclusively cites a single source, mostly for its list of the features and locations in the Lowerdark: the [*Underdark* 3.5e sourcebook](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Underdark_(sourcebook)) by Bruce R. Cordell, Gwendolyn F.M. Kestrel, and Jeff Quick (available [here on DMsGuild](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/28621/Underdark-%2835%29)). It might be worth pointing to that for further details.